# Improve tooltips area chart using Grafico

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, raphael

I am working on a requirement-->" it is required to generate a stacked area chart with tool tips".

I am able to do it using he grafico open source js published in this url http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/documentation/#basics

But when I try to customize the tooltip for the area chart, tool tip starts drifting from its position.

I found Google apis provides a better tool-tip from their implementation . please find the implementation on on this url https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#Stacking( here tool-tip does not drift from its position if I change length of text in the tool tip) and tool-tips are highly customizable.

The grafico tool-tip implementation is having issues ,but the google implementation is better. 
When i try to customize the tool-tip in grafico chart it starts drifting out of its position.
Also it is not possible to have multiple  text with different styles inside the tool-tip.
Any clue on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not customize Grafico since there were many issues.
So finally I used Jquery FLOT java script library and able to generate Stacked area chart with tooltip.
Jquery is really cool and easy to use, with so much help and support available online.